Prevent mobile vertical scroll on Google Sites page?
I have a simple website that, for some reason, has a vertical scroll when viewed on mobile devices.
Video: https://youtu.be/MIaD-Rp6-KY?feature=shared
It is very short and should not force people to scroll.
Can anyone help me to understand why this site has a vertical scroll despite its short length?

From the video, it appears that the vertical scrolling is the hiding and showing of the browser's UI above the page. The pages itself doesn't appear to be scroilling

Add a full screen overlay div with a centered alert for rotating phone.
set style="display: none;" and set it's z-index="-1"
<div id="rotate-alert-overlay" style="display: none; z-index: -1;">
  <div class="rotate-alert-content">
    <p>Please rotate your device to landscape mode for better viewing.</p>
  </div>
</div>

Include JavaScript that sets the display style to none unless page width > page height at which point it should be removed.
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  const overlay = document.getElementById("rotate-alert-overlay");
  if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    overlay.style.display = "";
  }
});

or most professional:
window.addEventListener("resize", () => document.getElementById("rotate-alert-overlay").style.display = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? "none" : "");

Also you can add this CSS to display better alert overlay:
#rotate-alert-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Semi-transparent black background */
  display: none; /* Initially hidden */
  z-index: -1; /* Initially positioned behind content */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotate-alert-content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}


Thanks, but I don't think any of this can be applied in the current Google Sites editor.

None of this makes any sense on how to fix this issue.
